# Trajectory toward destination point

Tags: java, android, libgdx, game-physics

I'm working on small android game with libgdx and I've been struggling for few days with physics.

Idea is simply to shoot the ball at designated location in a parabolic trajectory.
I found few topics regarding my problem and I got this equation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Angle_required_to_hit_coordinate_.28x.2Cy.29

***EDIT***

I came up with this code:

```
public void update(float deltaTime) {
    if (!freeze) {
        position.add(velocity.x * deltaTime, velocity.y * deltaTime, velocity.z * deltaTime);
        velocity.scl(1 - (GameWorld.GRAVITY * deltaTime));
        if (position.y < 1) {
            velocity.y = (- velocity.y/2)+1;
        } else {
            velocity.y += GameWorld.GRAVITY;
        }
    }
}

public void shootToward(Vector3 destination, float v, boolean direct) {
    float distX = destination.x - position.x;
    //float distZ = destination.z - position.z;
    float distZ = 0;
    float altitude = destination.y - position.y;
    float distance = (float)(Math.sqrt(distX * distX + distZ * distZ));
    double sqrt = (v*v*v*v) - (GameWorld.GRAVITY * (GameWorld.GRAVITY * distance*distance + 2 * altitude * v*v));
    sqrt = Math.sqrt(sqrt);
    float angle;
    if (direct)
        angle = (float)Math.atan((v*v - sqrt) / (GameWorld.GRAVITY*distance));
    else
        angle = (float)Math.atan((v*v + sqrt) / (GameWorld.GRAVITY*distance));
    Gdx.app.log("Ball", "Degrees: " + Math.toDegrees(angle));
    float newX = v * (float)Math.cos(angle);
    float newY = v * (float)Math.sin(angle);
    velocity.set(newX, newY, 0);
}
```

It seems to work for most people but in my case angle for positive solution is 89' all the time
and negative doesn't works either.
Tried to tweak values but it still fails.

Also, should the gravity be positive value or negative?

I would appreciate help

***EDIT***

Example shots:

```
v = 50 direct=false
Ball: Position: 0.0, 50.0
Ball: Destination: 100.0, 0.0
Ball: Degrees: -88.8654739323932
Ball: Velocity: 0.9899961, -49.990196
Ball: Landed: 0.8182346, -4.0932293

v = 100 direct=false
Ball: Position: 0.0, 50.0
Ball: Destination: 100.0, 0.0
Ball: Degrees: -89.71855772953862
Ball: Velocity: 0.49120748, -99.998795
Ball: Landed: 0.2182493, 1.7965958

v = 50 direct=true
Ball: Position: 0.0, 50.0
Ball: Destination: 100.0, 0.0
Ball: Degrees: -27.699576046892837
Ball: Velocity: 44.269855, -23.241776
Ball: Landed: 59.603405, 1.6399858

v = 100 direct=true
Ball: Position: 0.0, 50.0
Ball: Destination: 100.0, 0.0
Ball: Degrees: -26.846403457288204
Ball: Velocity: 89.22204, -45.160027
Ball: Landed: 73.34829, 0.033889055
```

Comment: Some details on how the behaviour differs from what you expect would be helpful to find an issue.

Comment: Hi, describe what you are exactly trying to do - for now your way seems to be very far from being proper. Do you use Box2d or another engine? Or maybe you are implementing one?

Comment: I simply add velocity vector to position on update